# NSTableViewHeaderView not drawing over NSScroller

Tags: macos, nsscroller, nstableheaderview

I've got a custom NSTableHeaderView of custom NSTableHeaderCell objects that draw a custom header. The problem I'm having is that when the NSScroller bars show up, the header drawn above the scroller is the default, not my custom drawing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the view that controls this section (over the scroller, right side of header) is called cornerView and the NSTableView has a -setCornerView:(NSView *)view method to set it. I fixed my problem by subclassing NSView and using custom drawing to draw a corner image into the view, then setting that subclass using the previously mentioned method.

Comment: This was one of the most mystical things I was trying to solve on Cocoa. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Mac Mojave Left Corner View**

Recently when providing support for one of my application on Mac Mojave I find out the culprit behind the top left corner view of table view. this can also be removed if we will set the corner view from xib like below.

**This issue produces if Automatically Hide Scroller property is set to YES and no corner view has been set**

[image: patch showing on top left corner of table view]

**Solution:**

[image: setting corner view property]